# Exif data biggest issue!Not returning correct values for images in android

Tags: android, image, exif

Good day guys.Im trying to check the orientation of images in gallery which have been captured by android default camera.So here we go with horrible and angry full issue.For anti-clockwise rotation with 90 degree the damned exif returns `ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90`..Ok lets assume its ok..but problem is that for clockwise rotation of 90 degree the damned exif returns same!So couple images got mixed.For example i got 2 images,one taken anti-clockwise with 90 degree and second one taken with clockwise 90 degree,but their both exif values are `ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90` so whenever i see this tag i just rotate 90 degree and one image rotates correctly but another one of course no,because it must be rotated with negative value like -90..So please tell me what to do?Here is my code for getting exif data.

```
 public static int getRotationFromExif(String path) {
    try {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);
        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        Log.d("dadada",orientation+"");
        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
            return 180;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            return 90;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            return 270;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {
            return Rotation.ROTATION_NORMAL;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
            return Rotation.ROTATION_UNDEFINED;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This to be the seamless pain because client already got me killed because of non-right images rotation inside the gallery list view of the app...Please kindly help and tell if this is not possible to get correct information,is there any library which will normally tell the orientation or at least rotate the bitmap accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

If you have path and bitmap of image then you can use below method which will make your image rotate accordingly:

```
public Bitmap checkRotation(String filePath, Bitmap scaledBitmap) {
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scaledBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: problem is that for anti-clockwise rotation of image and clockwise rotation of image THE EXIF RETURNS SAME VALUE! so i can't differ them!so one image rotates to left another one rotatets correctly.i must get the value WAS IT RETURNED ANTI CLOCKWISE OR CLOCKWISE so i will know should i rotate 90 OR -90 degree,thats my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        try {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            int nh = (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * (1024.0 / bitmap.getWidth()));
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1024, nh, true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(scaled);

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            }
            else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
            }
            else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
            }
            scaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, scaled.getWidth(), scaled.getHeight(), matrix, true); // rotating bitmap
            imageView.setImageBitmap(scaled);

           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After the Bitmap has been retrieved the above code will scale down, rotate and display the image in an image view.